# What is a valid format for params in news bing url?

Tags: azure-cognitive-services, bing-search

I'm trying to add some filters to request for news in bing api but currently I don't get any effects of doing this ( for example filter for news from current month).

I'm trying to this with : https://api.cognitive.microsoft.com/bing/v5.0/news/search?freshness=month&?category=business , and replacing some filters here but I always getting the same result.

Currently i want to add three filters : freshness, category and language for news from current day and month.

So it is bug or I'm doing something wrong with filters ?

Answer (score 3):

One problem is that you have an extra "?" in your query. You only need the first one, and then you can use "&" to delimit individual parameters:

```
https://api.cognitive.microsoft.com/bing/v5.0/news/search?freshness=month&category=business
```

You might also try adding a market to the query string, like so:

```
 https://api.cognitive.microsoft.com/bing/v5.0/news/search?freshness=month&category=business&mkt=en-us
```

I'm using 7.0 and don't know what headers you're passing, so I can't test this directly, but it's possible a default market isn't being set. Since categories are market specific, then depending on how Bing handles this, it could plausibly prevent your category from being used.